# Replacing lights

Tags: bulb, light-bulb

Sorry its my first time replacing this kind of lights(not sure what do you even call them) but can someone let me know how to replace the busted bulb for this kind of lights. They are light we used in our ceiling living room

[image: Close up shot]

Top: The bulb is busted and need to replace, but in order for me to replace them I need to take them off first which I am not sure how..

Bottom: Here is a side by side on a bulb that is working beside it.

[image: 2nd bulb busted and need to be replace]

Update: I try unscrew(turning left and right) but its just moving and nothing happening.
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pretty unusual for an LED to fail. Is it quality?  Is it an eBay cheapie (note Amazon is all the eBay crud)?  Can you link the product?

Comment: Many of the early LED fixtures were not made to replace the parts, almost all of the failures I have seen have been from the driver failing (driver = electronics to convert line voltage to DC voltage & current needed). The fixture may have to be removed completely.

Comment: oh really you cannot change the bulb of this thing? this was the lights of the previous owners it failed after 2 month we got the property..

Comment: I have no knowledge with fixing electricity, if I need to replace the whole thing I have no choice but to hire an electrician.. Thanks for confirming guys, my wife is asking me to replace this bulb for sometime now.

Answer (score 0):

They look like LED bulbs in standard ceiling cans.  Did you try to unscrew them?

Comment: Hi @Dave D thanks for commenting I tried turning the inner circle(see new picture above with blue circle) but nothing is happening, I mean I can turn it to less than a quarter but that it